# How to shade bounded region of a plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have the following function

`f[z_] := Piecewise[{{Cos[z] - 17 Sin[z]/z, z > 0}, {Cosh[z] - 17 Sinh[z]/z, z <= 0}}]`

I am interested in the regions where $\vert f(z)\vert \leq 1$, I tried to shade that region using `Filling`, but my results were not the expected, how should I write the code? Here is my attempt:

```
Plot[{f[z], -1, 1}, {z, -5, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}, Filling -> {1 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

To be more precise: I want to shade the region $D=\{(x,y):\vert f(x) \vert<1\text{ and } \vert y \vert <1   \}$

Comment: Is this not what you want: `Filling -> {2 -> {3}}` ?

Comment: does `Plot[{f[z], ConditionalExpression[f[z], -1 < f[z] < 1], -1, 
  1}, {z, -25, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None, Dashed, Dashed}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, Cyan}, 2 -> {{4}, Cyan}}, PlotPoints -> 100]` give what you need?

Comment: .. or `Plot[{f[z], ConditionalExpression[f[z], -1 < f[z] < 1], -1, 
  1}, {z, -25, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None, Dashed, Dashed}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, Cyan}}, PlotPoints -> 100]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes! That is what I wanted, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[{f[z], ConditionalExpression[f[z], -1 < f[z] < 1], -1, 1}, {z, -25, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None, Dashed, Dashed}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, Cyan}, 2 -> {{4}, Cyan}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Also

```
Plot[{f[z], Clip[f[z], {-1, 1}, {Null, Null}], -1, 1}, {z, -25, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None, Dashed, Dashed}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, Cyan}, 2 -> {{4}, Cyan}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 1):

If the answer to my question in the comments is 'no', then perhaps this:

```
Plot[{f[z], Clip[f[z]], -1, 1}, {z, -25, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None, Dashed, Dashed}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> Axis}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for, I edited my question to be more precise regarding the region I wish to shade